# What is the efficient way to count number of items of a user in database

Tags: database, server, count

How should I count the number of items a user has added to my database?

1. Search all items and find that user's items.
2. Make a userInfo object and add a property like numberOfItemsAdded. Then each time the user adds or removes something, the numberOfItemsAdded will increase or decrease by 1 accordingly.

The first option, I think, will take more time in case of large number of items, while for the second option I have to write more code.
Which one is more efficient?

Comment: The second approach would be better, to save runtime